# Can I include code licensed under MPL within a project under MIT license?

Tags: licensing, mit-license, mpl

I would like to know if it is possible to include source code licensed under:

- Mozilla Public License (MPL) version 2.0

In a project licensed with:

- The MIT License (MIT)

If yes I would like to ask:

- Can I modify the code from MPL, but keeping their credits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can combine code that is licensed under MPL 2.0 into a project that contains source code from one or more other licenses, including the MIT License. However, the individual source files licensed under the MPL will need to remain licensed under the MPL, including any modifications that you make to the MPL-licensed files. If you modify any MPL files, you are expected to keep the credits to any previous authors or contributors, but you can add your own line.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix MPL and MIT licensed code in the same project.

What you can't do (without the permission of it's copyright holders) is remove the MPL license from the code. This means that if you or anyone else wants to distribute the combined source tree or binaries built from both the MIT and MPL parts of it it they must comply with both licenses.

Accepting code under more restrictive licenses into your project effectively changes the license terms for people who want to use the project as a whole. This is especially true if it's not possible to exclude the more-restricted code at build-time. As a project maintainer that is not a descision to be taken lightly and could well lead to your project getting forked.